# Mongoose: validation error path is required

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to save a new document in mongodb with mongoose, but I am getting `ValidationError: Path 'email' is required., Path 'passwordHash' is required., Path 'username' is required.` even though I am supplying email, passwordHash and username.

Here is the user schema.

```
    var userSchema = new schema({
      _id: Number,
      username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
      passwordHash: { type: String, required: true },
      email: { type: String, required: true },
      admin: Boolean,
      createdAt: Date,
      updatedAt: Date,
      accountType: String
    });
```

This is how I am creating and saving the user object.

```
    var newUser = new user({

      /* We will set the username, email and password field to null because they will be set later. */
      username: null,
      passwordHash: null,
      email: null,
      admin: false

    }, { _id: false });

    /* Save the new user. */
    newUser.save(function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log("Can't create new user: %s", err);

    } else {
     /* We succesfully saved the new user, so let's send back the user id. */

    }
  });
```

So why does mongoose return a validation error, can I not use `null` as temporary value?

Comment: Well I don't see where you are setting the newUsers email, passwordHash and username. you are setting them to null then attempting to save it.

Comment: Can you not do that? `null` is a value.

Comment: I was searching same issue. Turns out I was doing so create({ ...stuff }, { new: true })... The options not good !

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In response to your last comment.

You are correct that null is a value type, but null types are a way of telling the interpreter that it has *no value*. therefore, you must set the values to any non-null value or you get the error. in your case set those values to empty Strings. i.e.

```
var newUser = new user({

  /* We will set the username, email and password field to null because they will be set later. */
  username: '',
  passwordHash: '',
  email: '',
  admin: false

}, { _id: false });
```

Comment: Some people may run into an issue where Mongoose treats empty strings like absent values as well. There is a workaround here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7150

Answer (score 10):

I came across this post when I was looking for resolution for the same problem - validation error even though values were passed into the body.
Turns out that I was missing the bodyParser

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

I did not initially include the bodyParser as it was supposed to be included with the latest version of express. Adding above 2 lines resolved my validation errors.

Answer (score 8):

Well, the following way is how I got rid of the errors. I had the following schema:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Please enter your name',
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique:true,
        required: 'Please enter your email',
        trim: true,
        lowercase:true,
        validate: [{ validator: value => isEmail(value), msg: 'Invalid email.' }]
    },
    password: {
        type: String/
        required: true
    },
    // gender: {
    //     type: String
    // },
    resetPasswordToken:String,
    resetPasswordExpires:Date,
});
```

and my terminal throw me the following log and then went into infinite reload on calling my register function:

> (node:6676) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): ValidationError: password: Path
>   `password` is required., email: Invalid email.
>
> (node:6676) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections
>   are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
>   will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

So, as it said Path 'password' is required, I commented the `required:true` line out of my model and  `validate:email` line out of my model.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you are doing this correctly, but if you add bootstrap or any other library element, they already have validators.
So, ***you can remove validators from `userSchema`***.

Here, in phone attributes, you can remove "required: true" because it is already checked in bootstrap and other libraries/dependencies.

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Please enter your name',
    trim: true
},
phone: {
    type: number,
    required: true
} });
```

Answer (score 3):

When working with Postman you should make sure that you have sending Body>>raw>>JSON type (in my case it was Text instead of JSON)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same err so what I did is any field I required in my model I had to make sure it appears in the new User Obj in my services or anywhere you have yours

```
const newUser = new User({
    nickname: Body.nickname,
    email: Body.email,
    password: Body.password,
    state: Body.state,
    gender:Body.gender,
    specialty:Body.specialty
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the quick and dirty fix was to remove `encType="multipart/form-data"` from my input form field.

Before, `<form action="/users/register" method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data">`

and, after `<form action="/users/register" method="POST">`

Answer (score 1):

Try after removing some of your required fields in **name, user, sender anything**...
Like this ...
**I removed the required from the sender and it worked**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userModel = mongoose.Schema(
  {
     //sender: { type: String, **required: true** }  **from**    
    sender: { type: String}, **// to**
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default:
        "https://icon-library.com/images/anonymous-avatar-icon/anonymous-avatar-icon-25.jpg",
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const User = mongoose.model("User", userModel);

module.exports = User;
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this type of error

```
ValidationError: Path 'email' is required.
```

your email is set required in Schema, But no value is given or email field is not added on model.

If your email value may be empty set default value in model or set allow("") in validatior.
like

```
 schemas: {
    notificationSender: Joi.object().keys({
        email: Joi.string().max(50).allow('')
    })
  }
```

I think will solve this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. turns out i was importing the wrong model. check first your imports. and dont set null values to null, instead set them to -1 for integers or ' ' for strings

Answer (score -1):

I also ran into the same error

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       required: true,
      ref: 'User',
    },
    orderItems: [
      {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        qty: { type: Number, required: true },
        image: { type: String, required: true },
        price: { type: Number, required: true },
        product: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          required: true,
          ref: 'Product',
        },
      },
    ],
    shippingAddress: {
      address: { type: String, required: true },
      city: { type: String, required: true },
      postalCode: { type: String, required: true },
      country: { type: String, required: true },
    },
    paymentMethod: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    paymentResult: {
      id: { type: String },
      status: { type: String },
      update_time: { type: String },
      email_address: { type: String },
    },
    taxPrice: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0.0,
    },
    shippingPrice: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0.0,
    },
    totalPrice: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0.0,
    },
    isPaid: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
    paidAt: {
      type: Date,
    },
    isDelivered: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
    deliveredAt: {
      type: Date,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);

export default Order;
```

And below was the error in my terminal:

> message: "Order validation failed: user: Path `user` is required."

All I did was to remove required from the user and everything worked fine.

Comment: This is not the solution, if that is a required nested field it should stay like that.

Answer (score -2):

You Just Simply Add `app.use(express.json());` And It Should Work Properly.