# Path `isuser` is required

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am requesting a api in react to mongodb like
This is my constructor

```
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            email:'',
            eemail:'',
            password:'',
            epassword:'',
            mobile:'',
            emobile:'',
            isadmin:'yes',
            isprinter:'yes',
            isuser:'yes',
        }
    }
```

And calling api in form submit function like this

```
    formSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let error=0;
        if(this.state.email===''){
            this.setState({eemail:"This field is require"})
            error=1
        }
        if(!error){
            console.log(this.state)
            const admin = {
              email: this.state.email,
              password: this.state.password,
              mobile: this.state.mobile,
              isadmin: this.state.isadmin,
              isuser: this.state.isuser,
              isprinter: this.state.isprinter,
            }

            axios.post("http://localhost:5000/admin/add",admin)
            .then(res=>console.log(res))
        }
    }
```

It's giving me

> Error: ValidationError: isuser: Path `isuser` is required., isprinter:
>   Path `isprinter` is required., isadmin: Path `isadmin` is required.
>   even i am passing all these parameters.
>   I had tried true as well instead of yes and i am having String data type in mongodb models

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose: validation error path is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663665/mongoose-validation-error-path-is-required)

Comment: but he was sending null but i am sending value and it's giving me in inuser,inadmin,inprinter only

Comment: @vivek modi Can you print the `admin `???

Comment: @subburaj do you want admin model?

Comment: @vivek modi No. Before sending there request , can you print the `admin`?

Comment: @vivek modi Also your condition `if(this.state.email==='')` will satisfy and it will go into if and there I wont see any API Call??